# Refreshing resubmits form twice Error

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have looked around and found that using:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

will help me prevent the form to be resubmitted after refreshing the page. However, this doesn't work and I am getting an error on top of my webpage saying Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by....

I read that you cannot place the header tag after any html tags and whatnot and I placed this header code right after the data is submitted into the database. Please help me!

Comment: without seeing the rest of your code, try adding `exit;` right after the live above.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a most popular question on this site, it's indeed most of time being answered incorrectly.

What you really need to read is **the very error message you have**. It is telling you the **line** and the **file name**, where output has been started. To make you an idea where to look for the extra output.

So, you can sort the tings out even yourself.
The only issue you may need help with is Byte Order Mark which have to be removed manually, if being cause of the problem

Answer (score -1):

A single emtpy space at the beginning of the file (or an included one) will do that to you. Clean the output buffer before setting any header data.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-clean.php

Comment: Dear Downvoter, I'd like to know what you thought was so bad about this answer that it needed a downvote. Please leave a short comment!